# Method restriction in Java

Tags: java, methods

I have a class as follows,

```
public class Class1 {
    public void method1(String data){         
    }
    public void method2(String data){
    }
}
```

And i am  using it as,

```
public class Class2{
    public void doSomething(){
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.method1("123");
        // doSomething will find a value as result
        class1.method2(result);
    }
}
```

It is mandatory to call `method2();` when `method1();` is calling.
If only `method1();` is calling i need to show a compile time error.
How can we achieve the same.
Like `Class2` i have so many classes are there in each the `doSomething` is different.

Comment: /*It is mandatory to call method2(); when method1(); is calling*. You always want to call method2 when method1 is called?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking! Can you please elaborate?

Comment: That is not the job of the compiler. You can e.g. try to write some maven plugin that enforces that restriction. But why not just call write `method2();` as the last statement in `method1`?

Comment: @CKing I need to do something after calling method1

Comment: @RakeshKR What about the other way round. Can you call `method1` without calling method2?

Comment: If you think you need something like this, then the design of your class is not optimal. You could make both methods `private`, and then create another method `method3` that first calls `method1` and then `method2`. Users should then call `method3` instead of 1 and 2.

Comment: @CKing my condition is that when ever iam calling method1(); compiler should tell that you need to call method2(); like that.

Comment: @RakeshKR I got that buddy. You didnt get my question. What happens when someone directly calls method2. Is that allowed or not???

Comment: @Jesper Thank u  for your comment. As i said my condition is that when ever iam calling method1(); compiler should tell that you need to call method2(); also. Is this possible ?

Comment: @CKing should not allowed.

Comment: @RakeshKR By should not allowed, are you okay with the method being hidden from other classes or the method should be visible to other classes but should be a compilation error when called? (The later doesn't make sense IMO)

Comment: @CKing iam ok with  method being hidden from other classes

Comment: @RakeshKR Then you already have an answer. Go ahead and accept it :)

Comment: Your example is still lacking, method1 and method2 should probably not be void, at least method1 should not be !? Otherwise my original answer would have been correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say what you are trying to achieve is a mixture of "cannot be done" and "should not be done" as long as you want the compiler to do it.

Ask yourself this: are the following code snippets valid?

```
class1.method1();
class1.method1();
class1.method2();
```

or

```
public void doSomething(){
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    class1.method1();
    callIt(class1);
}

void callIt(Class1 class1) {
    class1.method2();
}
```

or

```
class1.method1();
if (true) return;
class1.method2();
```

I doubt you can come up with a good and sound argument for those three snippets (and many more I could come up with). It boils down to: what construct of code fulfills your requirement of "it is mandatory to call method2"?

Basically that requirement simply cannot be enforced!

---

The only valid way is probably to change the way `method1` works: Let it accept a `Runnable` as argument which the caller has to pass in which gives the caller the ability to operate after the regular processing of `method1` completes. Then call `method2` from within `method1`:

```
public void method1(Runnable postRunAction) {
    // regular computation
    postRunAction.run();
    method2();
}
```

---

To make the example a little bit more complex if you want to use the return values of the methods:

```
public class Class1 {
    public SomeReturnType2 method1(Function<SomeReturnType1, SomeParameterType1> yourDoSomething) {         
        SomeReturnType1 something = /* your computation of method1 */
        SomeParameterType1 param = yourDoSomething.apply(something);
        return method2(param);
    }

    private SomeReturnType2 method2(SomeParameterType1 param1){
        // do some calculation of method2
    }
}

public class Class2 {
    public void doSomething(){
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.method1((theReturnValueOfMethod1Computation) -> {
            /* do what do you want to do with the return value + return what do you want to pass to method2 */
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the reason behind introducing `Runnable`s here?
At first sight it is a bit of an overkill for me, as what is asked for can be achieved with access modifiers.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz not if the *"// doSomething"* is something that only can be done outside of `Class1`.

Comment: Still makes no sense to me... Can you give an example, why do you use `Runnable`s here?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz I do not understand your issue, assume on time you call `method1(() -> doSomeDatabaseTransaction())`  and some other times you want `method1(() -> doOnlyLog())`. The usecase is up to OP - but *if* he wants to do *something* in between the calls to method1 and method2, this is a way.

Comment: @luk2302 Actually after calling method1().. I wnat to doSomething, from that i will get one result, from that result i need to do method2().  Like class2 i have n number of classes in each class the doSomething is different. I think u get my point.

Comment: @RakeshKR okay, I do understand that - the problem is you are lacking that information in the original post - *if* you would use some return of *do something* when calling method2, then `method2` should have some parameter - you can achieve that be altering my method and have the caller supply a `Supplier<ParameterTypeOfMethod2>` - if the *do something* depends on the return of method1, then use a different functional interface. I am confident my approach works in all those cases, you just have to clearly state your case.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks.. This is what iam searching for ;)

Comment: @luk2302 is any option in java7

Comment: @RakeshKR yes, you can define an abstract class `Function` which basically has the same method as the current `Function` and then create an anonymous subclass when calling method1 - will be a little bit longer but works just fine.

Comment: Upvoted this answer, even though you have built it up on mine.
Can you give me a hint on how to crystallize my knowledge on concepts you used? I can see that you used `Function` and a lambda expression, but it is not enough to be fully aware of how it works.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz for the record: your answer is very different to mine - the only thing in common is making method2 private, which is pretty self-explanatory as soon as you remove the requirement to manually call it. Regarding your question I only have one advice: use it, play around with streams and look into what actually happens down the line - what kind of objects you pass in when you call `map` on a stream or `forEach`, etc. And go from there.

Comment: @luk2302, I do not say that your answer is the same as mine (wouldn't give you an upvote); it's just built up on it. The `forEach` is one of the few I understand. Thanks!

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz take a look at `map` too, I think it uses a `Function<...,...>` as parameter for the actual mapping function.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Class1 {

    public void method1(String input){  
    //doSomething();
    //you can pass whatever parameters you want or leave it as it is
    method2(result);       
    }

    private void method2(int input){
    }
}
```

And then simply call `method1`:

```
public class Class2 {
    public void doSomething(){
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.method1();
    }
}
```

To see the error:

```
public class Class2 {
    public void doSomething(){
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.method1();
        class1.method2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the compilation error that the OP requested for if he calls method2 directly?

Comment: Try calling `class1.method2()` inside `Class2`.

Comment: But that's not what the OP wants. What you have done is hidden the method itself. It's like deleting the method. Ideally, method 2 should be open to calls independently. That said, +1 because this is a good answer.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz this we knows.   As i said my condition is that when ever iam calling method1(); compiler should tell that you need to call method2(); also. Is this possible ?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz The answer you given is not acceptable in my case.Actually after calling method1().. I wnat to doSomething, from that i will get one result, from that result i need to do method2(). Like class2 i have n number of classes in each class the doSomething is different. I think u get my point.

Comment: Another edit. Now, `doSomething()` is a method call. Besides I do not know whether I understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can/have to implement a nice design pattern: **the Template Pattern**

explanation:

imagine you have a class **Game** with the methods
**initialize();** **startPlay();** and **endPlay();** then is wrong to start a play if it is not initialized, or even more clear, is not possible to start a game that is not already been played...

so in your case, define a wrapper method that allows you to call the method1 and method 2 in the correct order your Application need!

## Example

```
public abstract class Game {
   abstract void initialize();
   abstract void startPlay();
   abstract void endPlay();

   //template method
   public final void play(){

      //initialize the game
      initialize();

      //start game
      startPlay();

      //end game
      endPlay();
   }
}
```

then implement the Game class

```
public class Football extends Game {

   @Override
   void endPlay() {
      System.out.println("Football Game Finished!");
   }

   @Override
   void initialize() {
      System.out.println("Football Game Initialized! Start playing.");
   }

   @Override
   void startPlay() {
      System.out.println("Football Game Started. Enjoy the game!");
   }
}
```

and the final executor class:

```
public class TemplatePatternDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      game = new Football();
      game.play();      
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a compile-time error, because, as far as the compiler is concerned, the program is valid.

In your case, you could throw a `RuntimeException` (or any other exception that suits you for that matter), by checking whether `method1` has been called, when `method2` is invoked.

For example, in `Class1`:

```
public class Class1 {
  private boolean method1Called = false;
  public void method1(){
    method1Called=true;
    // rest of method1 code
  }
  public void method2(){
    if(!method1Called) {
        throw new RuntimeException("method 1 should be called first");
    }
    // rest of method2 code
  }
}
```

Comment: *It is not possible to have a compile-time error*. Couldn't this be achieved through annotations?

Comment: What annotation could you possibly create, that would trigger a compilation error for calling a method without having called another earlier?

Comment: I don't know. That's why I asked and didn't suggest.

Comment: Oh OK! For a moment I thought you had something in mind, which I couldn't get my head around and I would be super-interested to hear :) Anyway, the problem is that the order of calling methods can be thought of as the `state` of the class instance in the runtime, so this cannot be enforced by the compiler: it would mean running the code, with all possible branches/patterns and checking whether methods have been called in the correct order.